# If I kill a delete query in mysql, will the rows all be saved?

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

Suppose I'm halfway through running an import, and instead of running

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_being_imported
```

I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `table_being_im` and hit return, only to find to my horror that I've just issued

```
DELETE FROM table_being_imported
```

Oops.  So I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and get told:

```
Ctrl-C -- sending "KILL QUERY 627" to server ...
Ctrl-C -- query aborted.
ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted
```

Would it have deleted any of the rows?  Just hypothetically, of course...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

hypothetically,... [some of those rows are now gone.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html)

> During UPDATE or DELETE operations, the kill flag is checked after each block read and after each updated or deleted row. If the kill flag is set, the statement is aborted. Note that if you are not using transactions, the changes are not rolled back.

Not that this is the time to mention it, but this is why Transactional queries are best when dealing with business-critical data.